# IF condition (element of array vs variable)

Tags: php

I have an if statement and the condition does not seem to evaluate to what I am expecting. I am comparing two variables, one is the result of a SQL query to MS SQL Server and the other is a regular PHP variable, i.e.: `$row[1]=="$searchString"`.

When `$row` comes from the SQL query the condition always evaluates to `false`, but when it comes from an array it evaluates to `true` correctly (see sample output). The following code illustrates this.

Note: `SQLgetDayTypesTable` is a function that uses `sqlsrv_fetch_array` and I know that this works fine.

```
    $dayTypesTable = SQLgetDayTypesTable($getDayTypesInfo);
    echo "From SQL Server: <br>";
    print_r($dayTypesTable); // Array from SQL Query
    echo "<br>**$searchString**<br>";
    foreach($dayTypesTable as $row) {
     if($row[1]==$searchString){echo "match<br>";}
     else {echo "nomatch<br>$row[1]<br>$searchString<br>";}
    }

   $dayTypesTable = array(array(1,'Weekday'),array(2,'Weekend'),array(3,'Special'));
      echo "Internal Array: <br>";
      print_r($dayTypesTable); // This looks just like the array from SQL query
      echo "<br>**$searchString**<br>";
      foreach($dayTypesTable as $row) {
        if($row[1]==$searchString){echo "match<br>";}
        else {echo "nomatch<br>$row[1]<br>$searchString<br>";}
      }
```

Output:

```
From SQL Server: 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Weekday ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Weekend ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => Special ) ) 
**Weekend**
nomatch
Weekday 
Weekend
nomatch
Weekend 
Weekend
nomatch
Special 
Weekend
Internal Array: 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Weekday ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Weekend ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => Special ) ) 
**Weekend**
nomatch
Weekday
Weekend
match
nomatch
Special
Weekend
```

Comment: Best guess would be a trailing space in the SQL data, or something similar. Could you replace the `print_r`s with `var_dump`, so we can see the string lengths?

Comment: When you compare strings maybe use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: `echo "nomatch<br>$row[1]<br>$searchString<br>";` should be `echo "nomatch<br>{$row[1]}<br>$searchString<br>";`

Comment: Why do you have to use so confusing debug style? :D Like, why wont you state No match: next to it and Match: same way? Why alternate weather the indicator which one it was is on top or below the actual test subject?

Comment: `var_dump` was an excellent suggestion, the string from the sql query is 500 chars long, while the internal array about 7 chars long. 
Yes, I will also use trim in the future to avoid these problems.
Thanks for your help!